# Unmarshalling an XML document to Oracle Object Type using JAXB annotations

Tags: jaxb, unmarshalling

I am trying to unmarshal an XML document into an Oracle SQL Object Type.

Below is the sample XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<order>
    <ordernumber>123-01</ordernumber>
    <customername>Idea Networks</customername>
    <item>
        <itemnumber>T-01</itemnumber>
        <quantity>1</quantity>
        <amount>10</amount>
    </item>
    <item>
        <itemnumber>T-20</itemnumber>
        <quantity>3</quantity>
        <amount>8</amount>
    </item>
</order>
```

Below is the definition of the oracle object type in oracle database :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Item AS OBJECT
(
     ItemNumber               VARCHAR2(240)
    ,Quantity                 NUMBER     
    ,Amount                   NUMBER
); 

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE ItemsArray IS TABLE OF Item;

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE ItemOrder AS OBJECT
(
     OrderNumber               VARCHAR2(240)
    ,CustomerName              VARCHAR2(240)     
    ,Items                     ItemsArray
);
```

Now I used Jpublisher to generate the java classes for the object

```
java oracle.jpub.Doit -user=scott/tiger -sql=ItemOrder -package=xxcmpon.order.test
```

I have got total 5 classes generated (Item.java,ItemRef.java,ItemOrder.java,ItemOrderRef.java,Itemsarray.java)

The ItemOrder class looks as below :

```
package xxcmpon.order.test;

import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes;
import oracle.sql.ORAData;
import oracle.sql.ORADataFactory;
import oracle.sql.Datum;
import oracle.sql.STRUCT;
import oracle.jpub.runtime.MutableStruct;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlRootElement(name="order")
@XmlType(name = "ItemOrder", propOrder = {
    "ordernumber",
    "customername",
    "items" 
})
public class ItemOrder implements ORAData, ORADataFactory
{
  public static final String _SQL_NAME = "SCOTT.ITEMORDER";
  public static final int _SQL_TYPECODE = OracleTypes.STRUCT;

  protected MutableStruct _struct;

  protected static int[] _sqlType =  { 12,12,2003 };
  protected static ORADataFactory[] _factory = new ORADataFactory[3];
  static
  {
    _factory[2] = Itemsarray.getORADataFactory();
  }
  protected static final ItemOrder _ItemOrderFactory = new ItemOrder();

  public static ORADataFactory getORADataFactory()
  { return _ItemOrderFactory; }
  /* constructors */
  protected void _init_struct(boolean init)
  { if (init) _struct = new MutableStruct(new Object[3], _sqlType, _factory); }
  public ItemOrder()
  { _init_struct(true); }
  public ItemOrder(String ordernumber, String customername, Itemsarray items) throws SQLException
  { _init_struct(true);
    setOrdernumber(ordernumber);
    setCustomername(customername);
    setItems(items);
  }

  /* ORAData interface */
  public Datum toDatum(Connection c) throws SQLException
  {
    return _struct.toDatum(c, _SQL_NAME);
  }


  /* ORADataFactory interface */
  public ORAData create(Datum d, int sqlType) throws SQLException
  { return create(null, d, sqlType); }
  protected ORAData create(ItemOrder o, Datum d, int sqlType) throws SQLException
  {
    if (d == null) return null; 
    if (o == null) o = new ItemOrder();
    o._struct = new MutableStruct((STRUCT) d, _sqlType, _factory);
    return o;
  }
  /* accessor methods */
  public String getOrdernumber() throws SQLException
  { return (String) _struct.getAttribute(0); }

  public void setOrdernumber(String ordernumber) throws SQLException
  { _struct.setAttribute(0, ordernumber); }


  public String getCustomername() throws SQLException
  { return (String) _struct.getAttribute(1); }

  public void setCustomername(String customername) throws SQLException
  { _struct.setAttribute(1, customername); }


  public Itemsarray getItems() throws SQLException
  { return (Itemsarray) _struct.getAttribute(2); }

  public void setItems(Itemsarray items) throws SQLException
  { _struct.setAttribute(2, items); }

}
```

The Item class looks as below :

```
package xxcmpon.order.test;

import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes;
import oracle.sql.ORAData;
import oracle.sql.ORADataFactory;
import oracle.sql.Datum;
import oracle.sql.STRUCT;
import oracle.jpub.runtime.MutableStruct;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlType(name = "Item", propOrder = {
    "itemnumber",
    "quantity",
    "amount"    
})
public class Item implements ORAData, ORADataFactory
{
  public static final String _SQL_NAME = "SCOTT.ITEM";
  public static final int _SQL_TYPECODE = OracleTypes.STRUCT;

  protected MutableStruct _struct;

  protected static int[] _sqlType =  { 12,2,2 };
  protected static ORADataFactory[] _factory = new ORADataFactory[3];
  protected static final Item _ItemFactory = new Item();

  public static ORADataFactory getORADataFactory()
  { return _ItemFactory; }
  /* constructors */
  protected void _init_struct(boolean init)
  { if (init) _struct = new MutableStruct(new Object[3], _sqlType, _factory); }
  public Item()
  { _init_struct(true); }
  public Item(String itemnumber, java.math.BigDecimal quantity, java.math.BigDecimal amount) throws SQLException
  { _init_struct(true);
    setItemnumber(itemnumber);
    setQuantity(quantity);
    setAmount(amount);
  }

  /* ORAData interface */
  public Datum toDatum(Connection c) throws SQLException
  {
    return _struct.toDatum(c, _SQL_NAME);
  }


  /* ORADataFactory interface */
  public ORAData create(Datum d, int sqlType) throws SQLException
  { return create(null, d, sqlType); }
  protected ORAData create(Item o, Datum d, int sqlType) throws SQLException
  {
    if (d == null) return null; 
    if (o == null) o = new Item();
    o._struct = new MutableStruct((STRUCT) d, _sqlType, _factory);
    return o;
  }
  /* accessor methods */
  public String getItemnumber() throws SQLException
  { return (String) _struct.getAttribute(0); }

  public void setItemnumber(String itemnumber) throws SQLException
  { _struct.setAttribute(0, itemnumber); }


  public java.math.BigDecimal getQuantity() throws SQLException
  { return (java.math.BigDecimal) _struct.getAttribute(1); }

  public void setQuantity(java.math.BigDecimal quantity) throws SQLException
  { _struct.setAttribute(1, quantity); }


  public java.math.BigDecimal getAmount() throws SQLException
  { return (java.math.BigDecimal) _struct.getAttribute(2); }

  public void setAmount(java.math.BigDecimal amount) throws SQLException
  { _struct.setAttribute(2, amount); }

}
```

The Itemsarray class looks as below :

```
package xxcmpon.order.test;

import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes;
import oracle.sql.ORAData;
import oracle.sql.ORADataFactory;
import oracle.sql.Datum;
import oracle.sql.ARRAY;
import oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor;
import oracle.jpub.runtime.MutableArray;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;

public class Itemsarray implements ORAData, ORADataFactory
{
  public static final String _SQL_NAME = "SCOTT.ITEMSARRAY";
  public static final int _SQL_TYPECODE = OracleTypes.ARRAY;

  MutableArray _array;


private static final Itemsarray _ItemsarrayFactory = new Itemsarray();

  public static ORADataFactory getORADataFactory()
  { return _ItemsarrayFactory; }
  /* constructors */
  public Itemsarray()
  {
    this((Item[])null);
  }

  public Itemsarray(Item[] a)
  {
    _array = new MutableArray(2002, a, Item.getORADataFactory());
  }

  /* ORAData interface */
  public Datum toDatum(Connection c) throws SQLException
  {
    return _array.toDatum(c, _SQL_NAME);
  }

  /* ORADataFactory interface */
  public ORAData create(Datum d, int sqlType) throws SQLException
  {
    if (d == null) return null; 
    Itemsarray a = new Itemsarray();
    a._array = new MutableArray(2002, (ARRAY) d, Item.getORADataFactory());
    return a;
  }

  public int length() throws SQLException
  {
    return _array.length();
  }

  public int getBaseType() throws SQLException
  {
    return _array.getBaseType();
  }

  public String getBaseTypeName() throws SQLException
  {
    return _array.getBaseTypeName();
  }

  public ArrayDescriptor getDescriptor() throws SQLException
  {
    return _array.getDescriptor();
  }

  /* array accessor methods */
  public Item[] getArray() throws SQLException
  {
    return (Item[]) _array.getObjectArray(
      new Item[_array.length()]);
  }

  public Item[] getArray(long index, int count) throws SQLException
  {
    return (Item[]) _array.getObjectArray(index,
      new Item[_array.sliceLength(index, count)]);
  }

  public void setArray(Item[] a) throws SQLException
  {
    _array.setObjectArray(a);
  }

  public void setArray(Item[] a, long index) throws SQLException
  {
    _array.setObjectArray(a, index);
  }

  public Item getElement(long index) throws SQLException
  {
    return (Item) _array.getObjectElement(index);
  }

  public void setElement(Item a, long index) throws SQLException
  {
    _array.setObjectElement(a, index);
  }

}
```

To the above classes I have added the JAXB annotations for reading the XML document.

I am trying to unmarshal the xml document and print it through a sample script as shown below :

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(ItemOrder.class);
        Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        Marshaller m = jc.createMarshaller();
        m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        try {
            ItemOrder orderx = (ItemOrder)u.unmarshal(new FileInputStream("order.xml"));
            Itemsarray  items = orderx.getItems();          
            System.out.println("Order Number : " + orderx.getOrdernumber());
            //Item[] itemo = items.getArray();
            //System.out.println("Item Number : " + itemo[0].getItemnumber());

            m.marshal(orderx, System.out);
        } catch(javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException e){
            System.out.println("Main: " + e);
        } catch(Exception e1){  
            System.out.println("Main: " + e1);
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }
}

[ttr12@rstnssiovm0015 test]$ java xxcmpon.order.test.Main
Order Number : 123-01
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<order>
    <ordernumber>123-01</ordernumber>
    <customername>Idea Networks</customername>
</order>
[ttr12@rstnssiovm0015 test]$
```

I am expecting the output to be displayed with the items as shown below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<order>
    <ordernumber>123-01</ordernumber>
    <customername>Idea Networks</customername>
    <item>
        <itemnumber>T-01</itemnumber>
        <quantity>1</quantity>
        <amount>10</amount>
    </item>
    <item>
        <itemnumber>T-20</itemnumber>
        <quantity>3</quantity>
        <amount>8</amount>
    </item>
</order>
```

I think I am missing some annotation to bind the items array, which I am not able figure out.
Can somebody please let me know what is the annotation I am missing and where to add that?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to prepare the ItemOrder object with several Item's in it programmatically and then marshal it to the standard output. The marshaled XML will obviously different from one you created manually. It will give you an idea, what is wrong with your original XML. 
You, presumably will be able to unmarshal that XML back into the Java- class without any problem.